# is there a way to update a column data in mysql where user clicks on a link using jsp and html?

Tags: java, php, html, mysql, jsp

Is there a way to update data in a MySQL DB when user clicks on a link? I'm trying to count the number of users who opens a link in my webpage. I would like to show the number of viewers for that link and with each time update the viewer number in my ("NoOfViews") column in my database.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Certainly. Since you can run a servlet from a link (normally or an ajax call), that servlet can then do plenty of things in the backend, including updating a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-hits-counter.htm

This might help to achieve what  you want